# SQL sysntax issue from the AWS lightsail only

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a problem with my following query. It is giving the `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC limit 10' at line 17` on line 17 is `$morePost`. I just got it in Amazon Lightsail - Amazon Web Services. What is the problem here anyone can help me in this regard please ?

```
$morePost=""; 
   if(!empty($lastPostID)) { 
      $morePost=" AND P.user_post_id < '".$lastPostID."'";
   }

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        P.user_post_id, P.user_id_fk,P.post_type,P.comment_status,P.watermarkid,P.which_image,
        P.post_created_time,P.hashtag_normal,P.hashtag_diez,P.post_title_text,P.post_text_details,
        P.post_event_id,P.post_event_page_id,P.who_can_see_post,P.post_image_id,P.post_link_url,
        P.post_link_description,P.post_link_title,P.post_link_img,P.post_link_mini_url,P.post_video_id,
        P.post_audio_id,P.filter_name, P.gif_url,U.show_suggest_hashTags,P.user_lat ,P.user_lang,
        P.location_place,P.about_location,P.before_after_images,P.slug,P.post_page_type,P.shared_post,
        P.user_feeling,P.post_video_name,P.m_product_name,P.m_product_description,P.product_images,
        P.product_normal_price,P.product_category, P.product_status,P.product_discount_price,P.product_currency,
        P.ads_status,P.ads_display_type,U.show_suggest_users,U.show_advertisement ,U.show_google_ads , 
        U.user_name, U.user_fullname,U.verified_user,U.pro_user_type,U.style_mode,U.user_page_lang,U.user_donate_message,U.last_login,U.show_online_offline_status,F.user_one, F.user_two   
        FROM dot_friends F FORCE INDEX (ix_user_one_user_two)
             INNER JOIN dot_user_posts P FORCE INDEX (ix_user_posts_post_id_post_type)
             ON P.user_id_fk = F.user_two
             INNER JOIN dot_users U FORCE INDEX (ix_status_istatus)
             ON P.user_id_fk = U.user_id AND U.user_status='1'  AND F.role IN('me','fri','flwr') AND  P.post_page_type IN('wall','market') 
        WHERE F.user_one = '$uid' $morePost GROUP BY P.user_post_id DESC limit 10
```

Comment: limit what?....

Comment: @P.Salmon Limit is 10

Comment: `ORDER BY <something> DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have already try `ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 10` but it is same. I think the problem will be come from `$morePost`

Comment: No, I see `$morePost GROUP BY P.user_post_id DESC limit 10` where `DESC` is a `GROUP BY` clause. Change that to `$morePost ORDER BY P.user_post_id DESC limit 10`

Comment: @JayBlanchard So, Why Amazon Web Services not accept `GROUP BY` ? Because I tried the same codes on other servers, I had no problems.

Comment: AWS doesn't care about your SQL syntax, you can use `GROUP BY` for grouping and `ORDER BY` for ordering. But you cannot use `GROUP BY` for ordering in any case.

Comment: You might actually want to try this: `GROUP BY P.user_post_id ORDER BY P.user_post_id DESC limit 10`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you for the friendly information.

Comment: Did that fix the issue?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes it is fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are two different commands so you should do this:

```
GROUP BY P.user_post_id ORDER BY P.user_post_id DESC limit 10
```